# SQL Adding two rows into one cell

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I'm doing a student project and has now done a displaying of some data into a Datagridview, as you can see here:

```
1   Beijing Potato  Beijing 123456  potato@mail.com Mr Potato   Potato              
1   Beijing Potato  Beijing 123456  potato@mail.com Mr Potato   Chips               
2   Fish Company    Qingdao 123457  fish@mail.com   Mr Fish Turtle              
4   Fruit & Stuff   Xian    234567  fruit@mail.com  Mrs Fruit   Sallad              
5   Connor Company  Jinan   345678  connor@mail.com Connor Si   Chocolate           
7   Cookies & Friends   Boras   255424  cookie@mail.com Ms Cookie   Beer                
6   Alcohol Limited Shanghai    456790  alcohol@mail.com    Mr Alcohol  Cookie              
5   Connor Company  Jinan   345678  connor@mail.com Connor Si   Flower
```

My problem is that I want to know if there is any SQL injection that allows me to add the "Supply" in to one cell, so that the Supplier Beijing Potato will only be seen on one row, but will have Potato, Chips in the last cell.

```
public void populateDgv()
{
    string sqlString = "SELECT s.SupplierId AS [Supplier Id], 
    s.SupplierName AS [Supplier Name], s.SupplierCity AS [Supplier.City], 
    s.SupplierPhone AS [Phonenumber], s.SupplierMail AS [E-Mail], 
    s.SupplierContactPerson AS [Contact Person], p.ProductName AS [Supply] 
    FROM Supplier s INNER JOIN Products p ON s.SupplierId=p.SupplierId;";
    DataTable dt = clsDB.fromDB(sqlString);
    dgvSupplier.DataSource = dt;
}
```

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products] (
[ProductId]     INT             IDENTITY (1000, 1) NOT NULL,
[ProductName]   VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL,
[OrderPrice]    DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
[SellingPrice]  DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
[CurrentStock]  INT             NULL,
[LowStockLimit] INT             DEFAULT ((15)) NOT NULL,
[OrderStatus]   BIT             DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[OrderQuanity]  INT             NULL,
[SupplierId]    INT             NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Suppliers] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Supplier] ([SupplierId]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Supplier] (
[SupplierId]            INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[SupplierName]          VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[SupplierCity]          VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[SupplierPhone]         INT          NOT NULL,
[SupplierMail]          VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[SupplierContactPerson] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SupplierId] ASC)
```

Comment: That has nothing to do do with SQL injection, but yes, it's possible. Which is your DBMS ?

Comment: I'm working in Visual Studio 13, and have created a local databasefile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `STUFF` combined with [`FOR XML PATH`](http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/):

```
SELECT s.SupplierId AS [Supplier Id], 
       s.SupplierName AS [Supplier Name], 
       s.SupplierCity AS [Supplier.City], 
       s.SupplierPhone AS [Phonenumber], 
       s.SupplierMail AS [E-Mail], 
       s.SupplierContactPerson AS [Contact Person], 
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + LTRIM(RTRIM(p.productName)) AS [text()]
                FROM Products p
               WHERE s.SupplierId = p.SupplierId
               FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '' )
            AS [Products]
  FROM Supplier s
```

- See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e74a/1).

Looking at your model, yo could easily remove `[SupplierName]`, `[SupplierCity]`, `[SupplierPhone]`, `[SupplierMail]` and `[SupplierContactPerson]` from your `Products` table, as all those values exist in the referenced `Supplier` table. Storing those values in several locations uses a lot more space without any advantages.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. The Products cell now look like Chocolate           ,Flower .With a TAB(?) in between them or like hitting space 10 times. I know it's only beauty flaw, but do you know how to remove the big space in between?

Comment: Using `LTRIM(RTRIM(yourColumn)` will delete all spaces before or after the cell content. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again! The Products table only has SupplierId in it, my mistake as the Copy Paste of the Supplier appeared two times. Ltrim worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you don't you use linq, and get it back as a list?

this.dt.Suppliers.Include("Products").Where(x => x.YourId == Id)

(The .Where() is optional, ofc)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you probably have two records for the "SupplierId" in your "Products" table.  To get it down to one record, for that supplier, you'll need to somehow determine which record you want from the "Products" table.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT distinct s.SupplierId AS [Supplier Id], s.SupplierName AS [Supplier Name], s.SupplierCity AS [Supplier.City], s.SupplierPhone AS [Phonenumber], s.SupplierMail AS [E-Mail], s.SupplierContactPerson AS [Contact Person], 
coalesce(select distinct productname from products p where p.SupplierId = s.SupplierId) as productlist 
FROM Supplier s
```

I can't test it as I don't have your DB. You might have to tweak it a bit. Copy and paste into your query tool and see if you can get it working.

Comment: COALESCE doesn't concatenate rows, it only returns the first null element, and isn't supposed to be used like that, AFAIK. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't work, I have update the post with the full table construction

Comment: Sorry about that. I see that STUFF works, I'll have to look it up!